# Why are Spark executors trying to connect to spark_master instead of SPARK_MASTER_IP?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

Using a Spark 1.6.1 standalone cluster. After a system restart (and only minor config changes to /etc/hosts per worker) Spark executors suddenly started throwing errors that they couldn't connect to `spark_master`.

When I `echo $SPARK_MASTER_IP` on the same shell used to start the master, it correctly identifies the host as `master.cluster`. And when I open the GUI at port `8080` it also identifies the master as `Spark Master at spark://master.cluster:7077`.

I've also set in `spark-env.sh` the `SPARK_MASTER_IP` as well. Why are my executors trying to connect to `spark_master`?